# Configure a Remote Server with PDO PHP and SQLServer

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Well!,
I try to connect to my remote server with a php script using PDO PHP, I have a **server A** (the server with my database), **Server B** (localhost with wamp server[php 5.5.12 and apache 2.4.9 ]).
I configure the server B with *php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts* and *php_sqlsrv_55_ts*, add the lines

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts 
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts
```

on my php.ini

the script:

```
$server = #IP of Server A
$db = #DB name of Server A
try 
    {
        $cnn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$server;database=$db;", $user, $pass);
    }  
catch( PDOException $e ) {die( "Error al conectar con SQL Server".$e->getMessage() ); }
```

And this script display an error :
**Servercould not find driver**

Comment: Did you restart Apache on the remote after adding the extensions?

Comment: Did you also install the SQLServer client software on ServerB?

Comment: @JayBlanchard yes I did!

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes I did. SQL Server 2008R2 native client